# how to play audio file from phone internal storage in android

Tags: android

I want to play song which is present in my phone internal memory (i.e.no sd card)
in music file of media file .

```
String fileName = "1.mp3";
String completePath = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_MUSIC) + "/"+ fileName;
 File file = new File(completePath); 
 Uri myUri1 = Uri.fromFile(file);
 final MediaPlayer mPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
 mPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
 try {
     mPlayer.setDataSource(getApplicationContext(), myUri1);
 } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {

 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You might not set the URI correctly!", 

Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

 } catch (SecurityException e) {

 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You might not set the URI correctly!", 
Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
 } catch (IllegalStateException e) {

 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You might not set the URI correctly!", 
Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

  } catch (IOException e) {

 e.printStackTrace();

 }

 try {

  mPlayer.prepare();

 } catch (IllegalStateException e) {

 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You might not set the URI correctly!", 
Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
 } catch (IOException e) {
 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You might not set the URI correctly!", 
Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

 }

  mPlayer.start();
```

Comment: Uzeeta, have you getting any error?

Comment: Put the code in code blocks

Comment: Format your code first.

Comment: In your question is written that you want to read the file from your internal storage but if you use `Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_MUSIC)` you just try to read it from the external storage.

Comment: no , there is no error coming in the program but toast show message    "You might not set the URI correctly!", please suggest solution to it.

Comment: @UzeetaSiloth Its clearly showing that your URL is wrong. Can you double check for it?

Comment: @pratt thn what should be the right url for this code

Comment: @UzeetaSiloth is your completePath variable returning proper poath?

Comment: @pratt no it is not returning proper path

Comment: @UzeetaSiloth ya so that is the problem dear!!!

Comment: @UzeetaSiloth check my answer below and try with it.

Answer (score 4):

Use the code below to get a file (audio) from external storage, and play music,

```
String path = Environment.getExternalStorage + "/"+ fileName+".mp3";
MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer();  

try {
   player.setDataSource(path); 
   player.prepare();                              
} catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
} catch (Exception e) {
  System.out.println("Exception of type : " + e.toString());
  e.printStackTrace();
}

player.start();
```

do not forget to put permision.

```
android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with below code:

```
String path = "/mnt/sdcard/"
MediaPlayer mPlayer = new MediaPlayer();    
try {
mPlayer.setDataSource(path+"/audio/sound.mp3"); 
mPlayer.prepare();                              
} catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}     
mPlayer.start();
```

*** be sure to have the .mp3 file inside /mnt/sdcard/audio/**

And do not forgot to give below permission in AndroidManifest.xml.

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

On some **Android devices** (in my case Android 2.3.3) playing audio from internal storage cause an error. This happens due to the fact that MediaPlayer is treated as 3rd party application and has no access permission to your application internal storage.

Here, an simple example to play the audio file **[tutorial](http://www.javatpoint.com/playing-audio-in-android-example) & [code](http://www.javatpoint.com/src/android/audiocontrol.zip)**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Load Musics With this code**

```
 private void loadAudio() {
    ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
    Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
    String selection = MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC + "!= 0";
    String sortOrder = MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE + " ASC";
    Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(uri, null,selection, null, sortOrder);
    if (cursor != null && cursor.getCount() > 0) {
        audioList = new ArrayList<> ();
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            String data = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA));
            String title = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE));
            String album = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM));
            String artist = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST));

            // Save to audioList
            audioList.add(new Audio(data, title, album, artist));
        }
    }
    cursor.close();
}
```

**Play music with this method**

```
 private void playAudio(int audioIndex) throws IOException {
     mediaPlayer.setDataSource ( audioList.get ( audioIndex ) .getData ());
     mediaPlayer.prepare ();
     mediaPlayer.start ();
}
```

**make sure you have Audio Class and put this in your Manifest**

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Answer (score -2):

You can do this like that (kotlin :)

```
 //fetch the audio files from storage
val contentResolver = this.contentResolver
val uri: Uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI
val cursor: Cursor? = contentResolver?.query(uri, null, null, null, null)

//looping through all rows and adding to list
if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    do {
        val title: String = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE))
        val artist: String = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST))
        val duration: String = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DURATION))
        val url: String = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA))
        val modelAudio = ModelAudio()
        modelAudio.setaudioTitle(title)
        modelAudio.setaudioArtist(artist)
        modelAudio.setaudioUri(url)
        modelAudio.setaudioDuration(duration)
        audioArrayList.add(modelAudio)
    } while (cursor.moveToNext())
}
```

In manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Bonus !!!
Checking permission (dexter):

```
 private fun checkPermissions() {
 Dexter.withActivity(this).withPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
        .withListener(object : PermissionListener {
            override fun onPermissionGranted(permissionGrantedResponse: PermissionGrantedResponse) {
            }
            override fun onPermissionDenied(permissionDeniedResponse: PermissionDeniedResponse) {}
            override fun onPermissionRationaleShouldBeShown(
                    permissionRequest: PermissionRequest,
                    permissionToken: PermissionToken
            ) {
                // asking for permission
                permissionToken.continuePermissionRequest()
            }
        }).check()
```

}

Dexter dependency :)

```
 implementation 'com.karumi:dexter:6.2.2'
```